# Simple AngularJS directive that gets a value from attribute

Tags: angularjs

I am building a website frontend using AngularJS 1.3.6. I would like to re-use some of my code as templates, and have it done as simple as possible. Preferably without using a controller.

I have a spotify play button link:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4FAAYTHgGpjZZgdSwVsfen" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The only thing changing is:

```
spotify:track:4FAAYTHgGpjZZgdSwVsfen
```

So I would like to make a custom directive in AngularJS which creates the iframe element when I write

```
<bb-spotify-play-button spotify-track-id="spotify:track:4FAAYTHgGpjZZgdSwVsfen"></bb-spotify-play-button>
```

I have tried this, but can't make it work, and I have trouble figuring the attrs object out:
(I know - this code is just an attempt to get something out of attrs)

```
app.directive('bbSpotifyPlayBox', function() {
    return {
        'restrict': 'E',
        'link': function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.text(attrs.getAttribute('spotifyTrackId'))
        }
}
```

Also, I would like to avoid using a controller for this, as I want to use the directive in as simple a way as possible.

Any suggestions?

Here a plunker to play with: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6eZSVFVQ4C6G0Wm1tosC)

Maybe it's also my habits from PHP and Laravel, where I would do something like:

```
@include('spotify-play-box', ['spotify-track-id' => 'xxxx'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you should do is [whitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#methods_resourceUrlWhitelist) resource in order Angulars `$sce` module agree to render iframe:

```
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'https://embed.spotify.com/**'
    ]);
});
```

then you can do something like this (note using `ngSrc` directive):

```
app.directive('bbSpotifyPlayBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            spotifyTrackId: '@'
        },
        template: '<iframe ng-src="{{spotifyTrack}}" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.spotifyTrack = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=" + scope.spotifyTrackId;
        }
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/N17ZqD0hAkIODatgBYOi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. So the problem was both getting the scope right, and also whitelisting the URI?

Comment: Yes, but the main problem was making allowed resource for iframe.